# Ubuntu 14.04 Apache 2.4.7 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I've been reading the forums and trying to replicate their fixes, but I must be missing something on my end since it will switch from a simple **404 Error Not Found** to a **403 Forbidden Error** (even after chown and chmod changes).

Currently, I am experiencing the 403 error code even after a sudo apache2ctl restart

Here is what I've done so far. 
- gedit apache2.conf with the following

```
<Directory /path/to/directory/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

- gedit sites-available/000-default.conf  && sites-enabled/000-default.conf

  ```
  DocumentRoot /path/to/directory
      <Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
      <Directory /path/to/directory>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
      </Directory>

      ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
      <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      </Directory>
  ```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What link are you trying to access? Does the file you want to access exist on the server (check for typos, too)?

Comment: There were no errors. I figured that I have to locate all the folders under var/www/html now.  Before I was able to relocate the folder anywhere as long as the path to the directory is the same.  For some reason it returns an error if I locate the directory outside of var/www/html/

Answer (score 0):

First note that you have now Apache 2.4, not Apache 2.2. The style to declare permissions has changed with Apache 2.4 and you should consistently use the new ones (like `require all granted`).

Apache has become more strict in what files it allows to be served. Essentially, arrange the files to be served outside in your Document Root and below, and keep all other files out of this tree. Don't link to files outside the Document Root tree.

Some point of your config:

```
 <Directory />
```

This is the root directory of your file system. If you declare anything for it, it should be `require all denied` and nothing else. Note that there is a difference between a `<Directory /absolute/path/to/some/directory>` directive and a `<location /relative/path/to some/location/on/your/server>` directive.

Configure your server in terms of `<location>`